# Validity of LTL formulas in a given transition system

Tags: modal-logic

Say I have the following transition system:

[image: transition system]

I've understood how I can tell if □a and ⟡b are valid (□a is invalid because a is not true is S2 and ⟡b is valid there is a state (i.e. S1) in which b is true. Please correct me if I'm wrong). But how do I reason the validity of the following formulas:

□(a -> b)

□⟡(a ^ b)

?